# How can I stop infinite cloning of a form field within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, field, clone

I'm more of an HTML/CSS person so JavaScript is still very new to me. I'll appreciate any help that can be given!

I found a JavaScript snippet on JSfiddle that almost completely meets my needs. I was looking for a way to clone a form field on a button click. Here's the problem. This code infinitely adds a new field every time I click the button. I really need the limit to be 2 new fields (so there would be 3 fields total). Then I'd like the button to disappear after the last field has been cloned so the user doesn't try to repeatedly click on it. I've attempted to tweak this all day with no luck. Here is the link: [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kXmpY/1/)

Here is the JavaScript:
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

```
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
    clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it endlessly adds fields per click or that it never stops letting you add one per click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already tracking the amount of duplicates made, so add

```
if (i === 2) {
    document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
}
```

to your `duplicate()` function to disable the button after 2 clicks

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etvztvqk/2/)

also watch your spelling! you have `onlick="duplicate()"` instead of `onclick=duplicate()` in addition to various mispellings of duplicator

Comment: I would disable it. A button disappearing can be jarring to users.

Comment: Ah! I just noticed when the fields are cloned, it also clones any text that was typed inside the previous field. Is there a way for the button to duplicate a fresh/empty field?

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter. It will check to see if the number of fields that have been created is <2 and then won't run anymore if it is > or =

```
var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

var count = 0;

function duplicate() {
    if(count<2) {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); 
        clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; 
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your if condition with this `if (i >= 2) {`, here we are checking if i is greater than or equal to 2, hence hiding the button.